# What should I do to move Electrum wallet from one computer to another (both are MacOS)

Tags: electrum, sweep

I have an old mac that I want to sell.

There are about 0.0001 BTC in the Electrum wallet on the mac. Though it's not some big money I still want to move it to my new mac.

I also have an Electrum on the new Mac and about 0.01 BTC in it.

Can I move them together? What should I do to make sure the money is safely moved and I can sell my old computer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just send the remaining bitcoin to an address from your new wallet on your new Mac. See [this guide](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/how-to-send-bitcoins-using-electrum/) on how to send bitcoin with Electrum.

Once the transaction is confirmed you can safely sell your Mac. The keys on your old Mac (which would be deleted by formatting the drive anyway) no longer control any bitcoin.

You can check the state of your transaction by searching for the transaction ID (which will be displayed in Electrum) in a [block explorer](https://mempool.space).

Make sure you have written down the mnemonic phrase (24 words) of the Electrum wallet (on your new Mac) on a piece of paper and store it somewhere safe. You can always recover all of your keys (i.e. all your bitcoin) with just those 24 words.